# how to stop my php page from continuing when field is empty

Tags: php, scripting, validation

```
<?php 
if(isset($_POST['submit'])){ 
echo "wht the heck"; 
$avail = new CheckEmptyFields(); 
$avail->availtime=$_POST['available_time']; 
echo $avail->chkFieldAvailableTime(); 
} 
else { 
print "<font color='red'>*</font>Printing else"; 
} 
?>
```

in my page but when i press continue the page goes on next page while field is empty.

beacuse i see "printing else" on the page even b4 i press continue so the script ran before while it should run when the user presses continue button.

Comment: wat ... is this a case where you should be using [`empty`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.empty.php) instead of `isset`? I can't tell.

Comment: Can you post the code behind your form fields?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST') {
   if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
      ... yada yada yada ...
   } else {
      echo '<font yada yada yada';
   }
}
```

With this, the isset will ONLY be checked if the page was actually requested via a POST hit. If it's loaded via GET or any other method, that chunk of code simply won't execute at all.

Answer (score 0):

The `else` statement is executed if `$_POST['submit']` is not set. On page load (before user clicks submit), that is the case.

Edit: Now that I think about it, did you put the two in different pages? What's form's `action` attribute?

Comment: action is the next page, method is post

Answer (score 0):

try replacing the `isset()` with `!empty()`, it could be happening due to `$_POST['submit']` being SET, but having no value. `empty()` returns true for, as the name describes, any type that is empty, see: http://php.net/manual/en/function.empty.php

So basically `isset()` will return false only if the variable is **not set**, but `!empty()` will return false even if the variable is set but considered empty (set to FALSE, NULL, 0 .etc). Give it a try.