# How to stop php empty field message to appear when page open

Tags: php, validation, scripting, input

i am using this code to print empty filed error

```
 if(isset($_POST['submit'])){ 
$oth1inp= new CheckInputFieldsAll(); 
$oth1inp->other1=$_POST['other']; 
echo $oth1inp->chkInputOtherOne(); 
}
```

this code is on page B, to print error when i submit page B.

But when i go from page A to B it prints the error.
as the page opens error message shows while it should show when i submit page B.

This question also sets  some context:
[how to stop my php page from continuing when field is empty](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5901138/how-to-stop-my-php-page-from-continuing-when-field-is-empty)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand the problem correctly you need some way of identifying whether it's pageA or pageB POSTing data to pageB.

You could include a hidden form input in the forms of both pages and check for it in the `$_POST` array as you're checking for the `submit` variable at the moment.

Another way of doing it would be to change the name of the submit button so that in the form on pageA it's called "submitA" and from pageB it's called "submitB"